# Tool (application or extension) that helping reverse engineer (okay-okay, just watch where and from) browsers' traffic under OS X

Tags: macos, reverse-engineering, traffic, httpwatch

this is my very first question on SO, so I'll do my best.

Every one know a really cool thing for looking through website's traffic under Windows – [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com). It is really useful program for developer and I'm missing since I've changed my OS from Windows to OS X.
So my question is "Are there some kind of alternative for this program (I don't mind if it is just extension for browser, or native app, or cmd line tool) under OS X and Linux/BSD?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to look at the web browsers traffic, you can use the Network tab of the Deveoper tab, which you can find on [Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/) by pressing F12. If you prefer [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/), you can try using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) as well.

But if you want to see the traffic of all applications, not just the web browser, I suggest you take a look at [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think `charles` is pretty well. It is a powerful tool to analyze HTTP requests. You can modify HTTP request header, cookies, queries by this software. However, it is not a free software. Maybe you need pay for it.